# Angularjs directive to make form dirty without ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-forms

I am using Angular 1.5.1. I have a checkbox on my form. I do not care about the truth/false indicator of the checkbox being checked/unchecked and so I do not want ng-model on it. What I care for is:

- when checkbox is unchecked, I delete a specific array from my model
- when checkbox is checked, I add an empty array back to my model

So I have created a directive that provides me with this functionality, very simple:

```
.directive('cbOnChecked', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            element.on('click', function(event) {
                if(element[0].checked)
                    scope.$apply(attr.cbOnChecked);
            });
        }
    };
})

.directive('cbOnUnchecked', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            element.on('click', function(event) {
                if(!element[0].checked)
                    scope.$apply(attr.cbOnUnchecked);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Now I can do something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" cb-on-checked="counter = counter + 1" cb-on-unchecked="counter = counter - 1"/>
```

Or

```
<input type="checkbox" cb-on-checked="deleteUserList()" cb-on-unchecked="users = []"/> No users<br/>
```

The problem with this is - the form within which the checkbox is won't get marked as `$dirty` if there is no `ng-model` on the checkbox. Is there any way around this?
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/s4gm6/178/) is an example js-fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: What is bad about adding `ng-model` and track its value in `ng-change`?

Comment: I will have a list of these checkboxes generated by ng-repeat. I would have to generate some fake variables for ng-model, like `ng-model="fakeCheckValue_$index"`, and then in `ng-change` handler make sure I know exactly which one was changed. This makes the code less transparent and straight-forward as to what is happening...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to go with your own directives you can just require parent form controller and mark it `$dirty` manually:

```
.directive('cbOnChecked', function() {
    return {
        require: '^form',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngFormController) {
            element.on('click', function(event) {
              ngFormController.$setDirty();
              if(element[0].checked)
                scope.$apply(attr.cbOnChecked);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: Just make sure you run $apply after your $setDirty, so you might want to move `ngModelController.$setDirty` into if block before `scope.$apply`: http://jsfiddle.net/s4gm6/179/

Comment: @dfsq in your answer 4th parameter to link function is ngFormController i read in angular docs and there it is controller i am so confused can you explain it to me.

Comment: Yes, this is a controller, but you can name parameters whatever you want. It  doesn't matter what name is the order is important though. The 4th is controller (or array of controllers).