# How to select first element from controller with angular

Tags: angularjs

I have two form elements in my template. I want to select first form element from my controller with angular and I am doing it like this.

```
angular.element('form:first').$submitted = false;
```

where is the problem? Its not working.

Comment: You can define ng-model for that and you can get them easily in controller

Comment: Can't add ng-model on form element. Its not requirement.

Comment: element[0] sounds good?

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915159/angularjs-directive-to-make-form-dirty-without-ng-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unnecessarily complicating things... If you give names to the forms (probably you've already done) then you can access them directly from your controller:

```
<form name="first">...</form>
<form name="second">...</form>
```

then in your controller you can do:

```
$scope.first.$submited = false;
$scope.second.$submited = false;
```

Anyway, if you really need the DOM form element, then angular.element is only jqLite wrapper arround a "normal" selector. So you can do it like this:

```
<form name="first" id="firstId">...</form>
```

and then:

```
var form1 = angular.element('firstId');
```

or, if you don't want to assign ids then use a name selector:

```
var form1 = angular.element(document.getElementsByName('first')[0]);
```